# Make outlook-instance visible in Word-VBA?

Tags: vba, object, pdf, outlook, ms-word

I'm making a word macro that runs on Document_Close(). I want the macro to open a outlook- "new message" window with no recipient, no subject, just a floder attached including some saved PDF's of the word template.

I've tried to do it this way:

```
Sub Document_Close()

ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument

    Dim bStarted As Boolean
Dim oOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem


On Error Resume Next


Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Set oOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    bStarted = True
End If

Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With oItem
    .Subject = "New subject"
    .Attachments.Add Source:="C:\temp\PDFSaves", Type:=olByValue
End With
End Sub
```

I know it opens an instance, because I printed it once, although I'd like it to pop UP on te screen so that i can manually enter recipient etc, and confirm that the correct PDF-folder was attached.

It would be nice if there was a oIten.Visible command...

Comment: `oItem.Display` https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-display-method-outlook

Comment: Doesn't work @KostasK.

Comment: Strange. It's working for me all right.

Comment: Yeah, going to do some testing in another document, I'll contact you again if I don't succeed

Comment: @KostasK. Are you saying that if I just put oItem.Display it will work? Can I see your code?

Comment: @KostasK. Nevermind I got it to work. Want to post an answer so I can mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MailItem.[Display](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-display-method-outlook) Method.

```
oItem.Display
```